# Passing data to server in remote validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Using jquery validation with remote on one of the fields. How do I send the data to the server of what the user entered into the field?

```
rules: { 
      "profile.userId": {
       required: true,
       minlength: 8,
       remote: {
                url: "/checkUniqueUserId",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                data: {userId : '???'}
       }
 }
```

How do I extract the entered value in the input field? I've tried:

- `$("#userId").val()`
- `userId`
- `profile.userId`
- `$(this).val()`

Any suggestions?

This is in my jsp:

```
<div class="control-group">
   <div class="form-group has-success has-feedback">
      <form:input type="text" id="userId" name="userId" class="form-control" 
      path="profile.userId" placeholder="user name"/>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show the HTML code where the id is present?

Comment: You need to post more of your code.

Comment: You don't need to do anything.  The value of the field is already sent automatically with `remote` rule.

Comment: Instead of showing the raw jsp, please only show the rendered HTML as seen by the browser's source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Quote OP**:

> *"How do I send the data to the server of what the user entered into the field?"*

You don't, because that is already sent by default.

Your code...

```
rules: { 
    "profile.userId": {  // <- this MUST be the 'name' attribute of the input
        required: true,
        minlength: 8,
        remote: {
            url: "/checkUniqueUserId",
            // dataType: "json",      // <- not needed, default
            type: "POST",
            // data: {userId : '???'} // <- not needed
        }
    }
}
```

If you just want the value of your `profile.userId` field, you don't need to do anything.  That's the exact data already sent by default.

Using PHP as an example, it is simply accessed server-side with the `$_POST` array as `$_POST['profile.userId']`.  (This assumes the rendered `<input>` element contains the `name="profile.userId"` attribute, otherwise none of this will work.)

You would only use the `data` option ***if*** you need to send *additional* data to the remote script.  Example, to send an email address along with the user id.

[See the documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/) for more information and examples.

Comment: yup, it comes by default, I just had to change the parameter on my server to match. Works! thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In somecase example: edit email user you can use data:{}

```
rules: {

            txt_email: {
                required: true,
                email: true,
                remote: {
                    url  : "emailcheck.php",
                    type : "POST",
                    data: {type:'edit',old_email:$( "#old_email" ).val()}
                }
            }
```

}

in emailcheck.php handle

```
if($_POST['type'] == "edit") {
    // your business code
}
```

Comment: Amazing, thank you so much, your answer almost saved my day :)